# Google Maps Android API v2: Visualizing the search radius with the helping of ValueAnimator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, google-maps-api-2

I want to add an animated circle to Google Maps view similar to the circle you see on this image.

[image]

The circle should be pulsing from the center to the largest radius indicating current user's location and the area of searching.

Here is relevant code block

```
Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(lat, lon))
     .strokeColor(Color.CYAN).radius(1000));
    valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
         circle.setRadius(animatedFraction * 1000);
         circle.setStrokeWidth(1 + animatedFraction * 7);
         }
        });
```

With this code I am only able to see static circle stroke without any animation.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply :)

```
    final Circle circle = MAP.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(EGYPT)
            .strokeColor(Color.CYAN).radius(100));

    ValueAnimator vAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    vAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    vAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);  /* PULSE */
    vAnimator.setIntValues(0, 100);
    vAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    vAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
    vAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    vAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
            // Log.e("", "" + animatedFraction);
            circle.setRadius(animatedFraction * 100);
        }
    });
    vAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Animation works until the markers will be shown. When markers are shown animation disappears. No matter where I  call `vAnimator.start();` it is not visualized anymore but at the same time I can see in the LogCat that it is processing. Do you have any assumptions why animation is not visualized with markers?

Comment: My circle has a fill color, but it dissappears when it's animated. What should i do?