# Blinking marker in android Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, reverse-geocoding

After long search on how to blink a marker i came up with this code in my project using google maps v2. Here is the code..

```
MyMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current_loc).title(address).snippet(city).
                        icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus4)));

                markertimer = new Timer();
                markertimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                blinkMarker();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 500);
```

here the blinkMarker method..

```
private boolean blinkMarker(){


    if(marker == true){
        current.setVisible(true);
        marker = false;
        }
        else if(marker == false){
        current.setVisible(false);
        marker = true;
        }
    return marker;
}
```

So the above is working fine and the marker is blinking , but my doubt is

1. will the above code use more memory for blinking?
2. and i'm using reverse geocoding for getting address, so not able to click the marker when blinking. Please suggest any other way to blink the marker?

Comment: please share your updated code

Comment: Refer this link,For Blinking Effect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278015/google-maps-android-api-v2-visualizing-the-search-radius-with-the-helping-of-va?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `setVisible` with `setIcon`. When doing that you need to prepare another drawable for icon with the same size as `bus4.png`, but with all pixels transparent.

Note [there is a bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5419) related to `setIcon` that causes info window to disappear.

As a side note a couple of problems in your code:

1. Using `Timer` is wasteful. It uses `Thread`, which you don't need. Consider using `Handler` instead.
2. You (probably) have a memory leak. `Timer` will not stop working when the `Activity` is destroyed. You need to `cancel` it if you don't do that already. If switching to `Handler`, rember to remove any `Runnable`s or `Message`s you send.

Comment: thanks for telling about memory leak and the bug, i've cancelled the timer in onDestroy(). I don't know much about handlers, so dint use..

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Google map is more busy: with many markers. So, you can use Scheduledthreadpoolexecutor with runnable.

Your blinkMarket method could be shorter, like this: 
'current.setVisible(!marker)'. I'm affraid that using Timer is not right approach. You can do the same using Handler with postDelayed. If the flashing of marker depends on some condition, that should be repeately checked, than flashing task should not be generated twice.